# php search html form variable name display on web url

Tags: php

I am creating PHP search form I want to display search variable name on URL my URL like this http://localhost/zblog/results/1/ I want to get like this URL

```
http://localhost/zblog/results/1/xxcxcxc
```

Here is my code

```
<?php  
$search = $_POST["search"];
?>
<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>results/1/<?php echo $search; ?>" method="post" name="search" id="searchthis" style="display:inline;">
<input id="search-box" name="search" size="40" type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for............"/>     
<input id="search-btn" value="search" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to change form method to method="get" and check $search get the right value.

```
<?php  
$search = $_GET["search"];
?>
<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>results/1/<?php echo $search; ?>" method="get" name="search" id="searchthis" style="display:inline;">
<input id="search-box" name="search" size="40" type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for............"/>     
<input id="search-btn" value="search" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I checked but same results getting

Comment: did you change the form method to get and for sure change the $_POST to $_GET too for $search variable.

Comment: This is not an answer. Post it as a comment instead